# harmon.ie bit9 execution block

Tags: harmon.ie

Our company recently joined a larger company that utilizes Bit9 for application whitelisting. Previously, we had a large amount of users using Harmon.IE to interface with our Sharepoint-based document management system.  I'm trying to figure out what to allow in Bit9 to allow the document open process to work in the Harmon.IE outlook add-in.

What's happening is the user tries to open a file from the Harmon.IE pane and Bit9 blocks the auto-generated, randomly-named vbs file used to launch the file from Sharepoint.  Since this file is different each time and has a different hash, we can't simply approve the vbs file.

We also can't set wscript as a trusted source as many malware sources utilize wscript.  Likewise, can't really allow anything that comes out of Outlook as that would open the door for malware delivery via email.

I'm trying to find out if there's a dll that I can trust somewhere in the stack that will allow these VBS files to be trusted and allowed to run.

Answer (score 0):

Add OpenFilesUsingScript key with default value "False"- harmon.ie will launch files directly without using VB script

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mainsoft\Prefs\OpenFilesUsingScript]
@="False"

Answer (score 0):

A custom rule with an action of Execute Allow on the path of the VBS with the name wild carded as deep as possible should cover you just fine.